# Indentation of some paragraphs in RMarkdown / Latex when exporting to PDF

Tags: indentation, markdown

I am writing a report in RMarkdown and I would like to indent a whole paragraph. I used this Latex code before the paragraph:

```
\leftskip30pt\parindent0em\
```

It works nice, but the problem is that everything below that paragraph is also indented. How can I specity the indentation to be applied only in one paragraph?

This might be an example:

```
One of the major issues seen in the manuscript is in the paragraph of the Method section that starts with Instead of rejecting teeth worn past… I found this paragraph somehow misleading.

\leftskip30pt\parindent0em
In case worn teeth were included, I would like to see which wear degree is your cut-off, i.e. following Molnar wear stages. For instance, we did not include P. robustus teeth with wear degree beyond 3, according to Molnar stages.

Concerning the Discussion, I followed the searching of the most likely explanation of this highly difference in PEH distribution present in P. robustus. and agree with the authors that the genetic one might be the responsible of these PEH.
```

The last two paragraphs are indented, when I only one the second one to be so.

This is the result when I export the RMarkdown file to PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the solution in RMarkdown:

By adding `>` at the beginning of the paragraph is enough:

```
One of the major issues seen in the manuscript is in the paragraph of the Method section that starts with Instead of rejecting teeth worn past… I found this paragraph somehow misleading.

> In case worn teeth were included, I would like to see which wear degree is your cut-off, i.e. following Molnar wear stages. For instance, we did not include P. robustus teeth with wear degree beyond 3, according to Molnar stages.

Concerning the Discussion, I followed the searching of the most likely explanation of this highly difference in PEH distribution present in P. robustus. and agree with the authors that the genetic one might be the responsible of these PEH.
```